# Batch file, trying to terminate a process with WMIC, and it works in CMD prompt, but not in batch file

Tags: batch-file

So the issue I'm facing is that after grabbing admin privledges with a UAC prompt, or even just having the batch file 'run as admin', the following commands will work fine in a 'run as admin' command prompt, but not in the batch file. Said commands are as follows.

```
WMIC PROCESS WHERE name="Agent.exe" CALL Terminate
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "name like '%Battle.net%'" CALL Terminate
```

After those two commands, which work in a command prompt, but not in a batch file, I also delete two directories, which fails as the application in question is still running. I just am at a loss for why WMIC works in a command prompt with the exact same context, and not in a batch file. I can share the entire batch file if it's really necessary, but those are the only commands not working as intended, and I'm entirely at a loss now.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using the **`%`** characters as wildcards, i.e. you're looking for a process which has a name with the string `Battle.net` somewhere in the middle of it. In a Batch file you need to double the percent characters! i.e.`WMIC Process Where "Name Like '%%Battle.net%%'" Call Terminate`. I'm assuming too that your process name only begins with Battle.net so you should isolate it better by just using wildcard at the end, i.e. `WMIC Process Where "Name Like 'Battle.net%%'" Call Terminate`.

Comment: @Compo Welp, I feel like searching a little more would have gotten me an answer, I had no idea it was simply just the wildcard. Yeah, this is part of a batch file to just close battle.net and it's agent and delete it's caches, so isolating it was actually a more efficient strategy, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`%`** characters act as wildcards for `WMIC`'s `Like` comparator, however in Windows batch files it is necessary to double those characters:

```bat
WMIC Process Where "Name Like '%%Battle.net%%'" Call Terminate
```

Your wildcards as written above though are actually searching for any `Process` whose `Name` begins with any number of characters followed by the string `Battle.net` then has any number of characters following it. I'm going to assume, more especially because of the strings leading capital that you don't really need the leading wildcard.

```bat
WMIC Process Where "Name Like 'Battle.net%%'" Call Terminate
```